# How come I don't need to reference "System.dll" to use the "System" namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am working on an assignment that specified "Do not use any external libraries". So I created a c# application, and the first thing I did was remove all the dll's references by default... including "System.dll".

However, I can still add this to my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
```

I was just curious as to how come I do not need to have System.dll as a reference in my project to do this. Thanks!

Comment: So, homework then? Also, I doubt "external libraries" included the .NET framework in its entirety. =)

Comment: I figured as much, but I removed it any way until I realized I needed to write to the console, but then I was still able to include those namespaces.. so I was just very curious :)

Comment: what would be the point of such an assignment? Mechanical engineers aren't told to "build a car without metal / established knowledge in math & physics / known concepts of vehicles and cars" either, or to say it simplers: "Reinventing the Wheel", prime example right here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mscorlib.dll` includes items in both those namespaces.

You need to right-click your project > Properties > Build > Advanced... and check "Do not reference mscorlib.dll" to remove this reference.

Comment: I wonder if the intention is really to not reference mscorlib.dll.

Comment: @Jeppe Yeah, I doubt you'd be able to do anything interesting without it. But if you really want to try it, that's how you can remove the reference.

Comment: Very interesting. But how could C# possibly function without e.g. the class `System.Object` (also in the `System` namespace, we notice) which is the base class of all user-defined types (of which there must be at least one in a C# program)? Maybe I should try this out myself. `System.Object` resides in the mscorlib.dll assembly.

Comment: I think you can write a console application with an empty `void Main()` that wouldn't require atleast one type... can't you? =D

Comment: You get an error `Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported`. If you then define it, you get ~30 more. But if you then define _them_... who knows?

Comment: Yep. Just noticed that. Interesting question. If the code can't even be compiled without mscorlib, why can it be removed?

Comment: I guess it's to let you implement the whole thing by yourself, if you wish. You know, use something like `Mono` instead of the Microsoft assembly.

Comment: If you do define everything (and it looks like stuff that language features depend on, e.g. `foreach` loops need `IEnumerable`) you then get errors in AssemblyInfo.cs and other hidden-y files because they're using classes that don't exist.

Comment: Well, Microsoft, when they build their assembly mscorlib.dll, write all the types and other stuff themselves, without importing them. So in principle, I guess you could write all that yourself, and compile without referencing Micorsoft's mscorlib.

Comment: @J.Steen Your first question: The `Main` method (like any method) has to reside in some `class` or `struct`. And that `class` or `struct` will derive (directly or through other classes) from `System.Object`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Oh snap. Touché.

Answer (score 3):

Different assemblies can contribute to the same namespace.

Even if you don't reference System.dll, you are still referencing (implicitly) mscorlib.dll which contributes many types to the `System` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

These references are probably defined in your `Web.config` or the `Machine.config` file so they're included by default.

Answer (score 1):

These are the default libraries.I think your question is that "Dont use third party dlls"

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to consider is, if you're compiling directly through the command line, a default set of switches, including default library references, is parsed by the compiler through the default response file (csc.rsp), located in the same directory as the compiler. The fact that you are able to import namespaces from the Base Class Library without explicitly referencing them at compile time is due to the fact that their containing assemblies are included in your program by default. To change this behavior at the command line, you can use the /nostdlib switch to force it not to include mscorlib.dll, or you can use /noconfig to have it ignore the entire default response file altogether. Also, I'm not too sure what you mean by system.dll, because the namespaces you mentioned are contained within mscorlib.dll. Also, I think by "external library", your instructor must have meant any 3rd party assemblies that would assist you in solving the problem. Anything that comes included with the .NET SDK would be more of a framework library. Unless your teacher is really harsh and wants you to reinvent the wheel :P